# python doesn't use updated pip scipy package

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, pip

I'm currently working with `scipy` and having problems updating it.
It is installed via pip and `pip list` gives me:

```
...  
scipy (0.13.2)  
...
```

But when I fire up my python and do:

```
import scipy
print scipy.__version__
```

I get:

```
0.11.0
```

Any idea where if got something wrong? Maybe the path? I was thinking python uses my pip packages as I installed scipy with it in the first place.

**Additional Information:**
Output of `which python` in terminal:

```
/usr/bin/python
```

Output of `print sys.path`:

```
'/Users/*MY_USER*/Documents/workspace/*MY_PROJECT*', 
'/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.4.1-py2.7.egg', 
'/Users/*MY_USER*/Documents/workspace/*MY_PROJECT*', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages', 'lib'
```

Output of print `scipy.__path__`:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/scipy
```

Output of `which pip`:

```
/usr/local/bin/pip
```

**UPDATE:**
It seems, another version of scipy is pulled first from
`/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/`
because it appears before the correct `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`

So if i run
`sys.path.insert(1, "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages")`
the correct version of scipy is loaded!

So how can i fix this ordering issue clean and permanently? Platform OSX Mavericks.

Comment: Is `scipy` installed in your global python? Also, what's the `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: Can you print the results of python -c 'import sys;print sys.path;'?

Comment: Additional information added above. @kroolik : yes it is, no virtual environments etc. and pip was not installed via macports but easy_install which could lead to some weird path problems i've heard.

Comment: Could you also add print scipy.__path__

Comment: @aplassard sure, info added above.

Comment: When you run pip install scipy does it tell you that you the library is already installed in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/?  On my mac, the pip install directory was not in the default python path.  I think if you run export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/:PYTHONPATH that should fix it

Comment: pip says: 'Requirement already satisfied' (i have upgraded scipy just recently) after the path export scipy.__version__ is still 0.11.0 and not 0.13.0. scipy (0.13.2) is listed under 'pip list'.

Comment: what is output for `which pip`?

Comment: @alko added output...

Comment: Can you open a python interpreter and manually remove the path that it's pulling scipy from and then add the path that pip adds the files to and see what happens?

Comment: Any other module installed via pip has its __path__ set to:
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/... except scipy, which is pulled from the path mentioned above. So there is another scipy installed? 
Funny is, the path where my pip-installed scipy lives is already in my path (last component). So is it the fact, that my "wrong" scipy path appears before the right one and therefore is used first?

Comment: Yes exactly.  Mac probably has a default scipy library installed and its ahead of the one by pip.  There are several ways to solve this so let me know if you need help.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply delete (or rename) the directories of old libraries or create symbolic links from updated packages. I firstly renamed, checked if everything works, then I deleted them.

In my case, pip is installing/updating the libraries in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python2.7/site-packages, so this directory always has the updated versions. However, my python primarily looks at /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python, where old version of scipy, numpy and matplotlib resides. When I deleted old versions, new python started loading updated modules.