# Python on Mac: How should I manage same modules in different directories?

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, numpy

I am having problems figuring out what is the best practice for handling duplicate modules with different version in different directories.
What I have done and figured out so far is the following.

I updated numpy on my Mac X (Mavericks) using pip which installed the latest version (v1.8.2) of numpy in the following directory:

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
```

When I tried importing numpy in an interactive session, however, python imported the old version (v1.6.2) from the following directory:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
```

It seems like this happened because python searched for numpy in the second directory before discovering the newer version in the first directory.

According to a [a previous post,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20762667/python-doesnt-use-updated-pip-scipy-package) you can let python load the newer numpy by change the order of search or by deleting the directory which contains the old module. However some say that [It is not a good idea to modify the contents of /System/Library/Frameworks](http://jessenoller.com/blog/2009/03/16/so-you-want-to-use-python-on-the-mac).

So what is the best thing to do?
Changing the order of the search seems like a good idea because it will not alter any files or directories, but will it cause any problems if I do that?
Or is there anything else that can solve the problem?

Comment: export path  System/... in your .bashrc so it will be checked first

Comment: Virtualenv?
http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/